# How to join two queries in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two queries on one table 
1st

```
select count(*) from busbooking.bus_boarding_point where busId=10;
```

2nd

```
select Check_Point from busbooking.bus_boarding_point where busId=10
```

i want that queries results in two columns

Comment: should this `select Check_Point from busbooking.bus_boarding_point where busId=10` return only one record?

Answer (score 3):

Add a group by clause. This allows to use aggregated functions.

```
select Check_Point, count(*) 
from busbooking.bus_boarding_point 
where busId=10
group by Check_Point;
```

According to [MySql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html):

> For the query to be legal in SQL92, the name column must be omitted
>   from the select list or named in the GROUP BY clause.
>
> SQL99 and later permits such nonaggregates per optional feature T301
>   if they are functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns

Comment: I have 10 records of busId=10

Comment: Bokadvira 1
Chinchpada 1
Dastan         1
Gavhan-Phata 1
Jasai         1
Kunde-Vahal 1
Owale 1
Pargaon 1
Sheva 1
Sonari 1
your query shows result like this

Comment: is it what do you expect?

Answer (score 1):

Other than using `group by`, you can also use `inner query` to get the desired result, e.g.

```
SELECT bp.Check_Point, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bus_boarding_point WHERE Check_Point = bp.Check_Point) as count
FROM bus_boarding_point bp
WHERE bp.busId = 10;
```

Comment: # Check_Point, count
Bokadvira, 2
Chinchpada, 3
Dastan, 2
Gavhan-Phata, 2
Jasai, 3
Kunde-Vahal, 1
Owale, 3
Pargaon, 3
Sheva, 2
Sonari, 2
Your query shows this result

Comment: Is that the expected output?